# How To Intercept a response that requires user action before replaying desired response to user

Tags: android, okhttp

I have a rather unique problem I have to solve. I am working on an app that uses a homegrown networking layer with the legacy okhttp client in Android and we would like to use Retrofit and OKHttp3 instead.

The problem we have is that our services may return a response on a user request that contains one or more actions a user must take before the server will allow the original request to execute and thus return the desired response.

It goes kinda like this. User tries to log in, but they are a new user, instead services responds with a series of information collection actions. If the user cancels they do not log in, but if the user executes the series of actions than the original login request is replayed and the user logs in.

I am taking a close look at the Interceptor interface provided by OkHttp3 as the means of achieving this.  Now I know I can intercept any response and modify it or do other things, but the interface method must return a value of type Response in the end. However I need the ability to "hold/prevent" that return from taking place before the user either A: Cancels the actions required by services, or B: Successfully completes those actions.

This is what I have so far.

```
private static class ServerActionInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ServicesResponse serviceResponse = null;
        if (response.body() != null) {
            serviceResponse = gson.fromJson(response.body().string(), ServicesResponse.class);
        }
        if (serviceResponse != null) {
            if (serviceResponse.getServerActions() != null && serviceResponse.getServerActions().size() > 0) {
                //handle server actions

                handleServerActions(serviceResponse);//this must complete before we can return chain.proceed IF there are actions the user must take.
            }
        }
        return chain.proceed(chain.request());
    }
    //this method may end up returning a value
    private void handleServerActions(ServicesResponse serviceResponse) {
        //process server actions 
    }
}
```

Its not a whole lot, the majority will happen in handleServerActions and that honestly is pretty particular to the app.  But the core of the issue, is what method should I employ so that the return will happen if there are no serverActions for the user request OR there are and the user has completed the actions and thus the true response is ready to be delivered to the client?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am also stuck in a similar place.

Comment: Yeah I did. I decided to create an abstract class that implements Retrofit's `Callback<T>`. I created abstract methods that the `onResponse` and `onFailure` call once they have inspected the response that was received by Retrofit. Additionally I had to implement an interceptor that overwrote the http response code as a 200 since we use a custom 400+ code for this particular situate and retrofit considers anything but a 200 an error. I than used my custom callback class in place of the `Callback<T>` that would normally be used.

Comment: @chinmish thanks for your comment/question. I posted my solution in greater detail as an answer. I felt the above comment may not have been sufficient explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to a comment, I thought I would share my solution.

It involved a custom abstract class that implements `Callback<T>`.

This is just a general example and the actual implementation would be up to the business rules for your project.

```
public abstract class CustomCallback<T extends CustomResponse> implements Callback<T> {
        private CustomExcetption encounteredException;
        private Class<T> clazz;

        public CustomCallback(Class<T> clazz) {
            this.clazz = clazz;
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<T> call, @NonNull Response<T> response) {

            if (response.body() != null) {
                T body = response.body();
                i
                if (body != null && body.hasCustomActions() != null && body.hasCustomActions().size() > 0) {
                    handleCustomAction(body);
                } else {
                    onSuccessfulResponse(body);
                }

            } else if (response.errorBody() != null) {
                  onFailureResponse(exception);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<T> call, @NonNull Throwable throwable) {
            onNetworkFailure(call, exception);
        }

        public abstract void onSuccessfulResponse(@Nullable T response);

        public abstract void onFailureResponse(CustomException exception);

        public abstract void onNetworkFailure(Call<T> call, CustomException exception);

        public void handleCustomAction(@NonNull final T body, final String path) {
          //handle custom actions.
          if(customActionsHandledSuccessfully) {
              onSuccessfulResponse(body);
          } else {
              //create your exception somehow
              CustomException createdException = new CustomException();
              onFailureResponse(createdException);
          }
        }
    }
```

Ussage example:
Keep in ming the reference to `SomeResponse.class` is something I needed for my implementation and may not be needed in others. It was used for gson serialization purposes as I needed to know the concrete class of the response to serialize it properly.

```
service.someApi().enqueue(new CustomCallback<SomeResponse>(SomeResponse.class) {
            @Override
            public void onSuccessfulResponse(@Nullable SomeResponse response) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailureResponse(CustomException exception) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onNetworkFailure(Call<SomeResponse> call, CustomException exception) {
            }
   });
```